# Why does attribute maxWidth not work for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

It seems that maxWidth has no effect on EditText.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFoo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="port"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    tools:targetApi="o" />
```

The above code results in the following:
[image]

If I set layout_width="100dp" as following:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFoo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="port"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    tools:targetApi="o" />
```

the width is correct:
[image]

Comment: I feel like `ems` is overriding it. try lowering `ems` and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I just checked in the IDE and it's because `ems="10"` is preventing the view from maintaining maxWidth 100dp. Apparently ems of 10 requires a larger width so it is overriding the maxWidth attribute.

Instead of ems go with minWidth to prevent the view from shrinking.

Alternatively, you can use `maxEms` and `minEms`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: No problemo. have fun